# Hydraulic Cylinder with Damped Track Constraint not aligning (2.8)

Tags: constraints

trying to make a cylinder..watched several tutorials and did the following..

1. Center the axis for Rod and Cylinder at the pivot points
2. Add an empty plain axis for the rod and the cylinder
3. Parent Rod to its Empty Axis and Cylinder to its Empty Axis
4. Add a damped track constraint from cylinder to rods empty axis
5. Add a damped track constraint from rod to cylinders empty axis
6. tried to adjust on the settings but cannot get the two components to align....

Appreciate any help

[image: Cylinder before doing anything]
[image: Cylinder after steps 1 to 5]

Here is the Blend file (added after FFela answered as it still does not work unfortunately).

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said with the same result. Then I added the damped tracks to the empties instead of the meshes and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[Here are 2 pistons one with with 2 and one with 3 sections](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0ft4lpgey9hfl4/Piston_Broke_damped_trackMod.blend?dl=0)

I got the solution from [Here](https://blenderartists.org/t/rigging-a-3-part-hydraulic-piston/1182289/2) after using the *track to* constraint instead of the *damped track* which I mistakenly took for a *look at* constraint from 3ds max.

The *Track to* constraint has all sorts of issues like spinning mesh the *Damped track* doesn't seem to.

I realize after 7 months you probably have solved this issue, but someone else might find my research helpful.

Comment: Hello can welcome, thanks for the answer. While example files are useful and welcome it is better to locally describe the process ideally with illustrations so users can learn from it, rather then get a ready made solution.